# JavaScript alert box redirects automatically to next page

Tags: javascript, php

How to create an alert box in php which prompt after successful validation of your password and redirect automatically to another page without pressing OK button?
I am new to web development, hence i know only one way to show alert in php i.e. echo "alert('Validation Successful');";
But this alert has OK button in that and redirects only after pressing that button. I need to redirect automatically without pressing OK button. 
Can anyone help me in this?

Comment: too broad a question; try something first

Comment: You means first show the alert box and then after x seconds redirect to next page ?

Comment: Exactly- @rahul_m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that, when alert box open on some line, javascript stop execution on that line until you close the alert box.

For the functionality like you,

you need to use dialogue of jqueryui as follows.

**HTML**

```
<a href="javascript:;" id="dialog" style="display:none;">dialog</a>
```

JS CODE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dialog").dialog({
    dialogClass: "no-close",
    buttons: [{
      text: "OK",
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog("close");
      }
    }]
  });
  var dialog = $("#dialog").dialog('open');
  setTimeout(function() {
    dialog.dialog('close');
  }, 1000);

  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "google.com"; 
  }, 2000); //will call the function after 2 secs.
});
```

You can get working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/swapper8/s3p4ks1x/) here.

Comment: Result of your code is same what I want but as alert box has OK button, I don't want that. I wanted to show JavaScript alert without OK button and it redirects to next page. Can you please help me in that?

Comment: I am sorry mate, there is nothing in there in javascript. This is the only way, you can achieve your requirement.

Comment: Thanks bro. it works... :)

Comment: Bro please solve this problem too.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42131033/how-to-fetch-top-two-rows-values-in-mysql-and-compare-it-with-value-of-session-u/42131884#42131884

Comment: Sure, first mark this as answer, I will start with your next one

Comment: done. Please proceed for the next one.

Comment: Check my comment, on next one