# How to fetch top two rows values in mysql and compare it with value of session user variable?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I want to assign 2 employees with least employee id's as administrator in my project. How to fetch 2 rows with least employee id's from mysql and compare it with current session user?

eg:

EMP_ID  |  EMP_Name

```
  1    |  Mike
  2    |  Peter
  3    |  Drake
  4    |  Oliver
  5    |  Andrew
```

suppose my current user is Oliver (EMP_ID-4), how do i restrict admin page to open from its tab and direct url from users except Mike and Peter? If admin page is opened by Peter (EMP_ID-2) or by Mike (EMP_ID-1) then it should open from admin tab and direct url access too. Please help!!

Comment: What have you tried ? Its straight forward query, by checking if user belongs to 1 | 2 thats it. "select id from employee where emp_id IN (1,2)".... if user not belongs to this, then dont allow else allow.

Comment: Thanks Rahul, but this table is just an example. Employee id can be 4 digit or 5 digit or 6 digit. I want to auto assign my admin while user registration. Whatever the top 2 employees are, they will be admin. As employee id will vary.

Comment: So I means, you are saying, first two registered users will be admins is it ?

Comment: and then you want to check if first two users authentication ?

Comment: @rahul_m: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps,

1) Once user will register, first two users will be e.g. say, superadmin(1) and admin(2) rest all will be normal users.

2) Now when a user will login, you need to save those user data along with emp_id into session.

3) Now, authorization, means which user will have access to which pages, you will fire query like,

```
select emp_id from employee order by emp_id asc limit 2.
```

*This query will give you only ids of those top users, which are registered at top regardless of 1 or 2 or any number.*

4) Check if current user's emp_id(which you have stored in session) exists in top two user's emp_id from query which you above wrote,

if exists,

then access to all page,

else

show an alert message, that you are not authorized or just redirect to your home page if any.

I am sure, you are now done with everything, if you follow these steps.

Comment: You're most Welcome mate !

Answer (score 0):

for this exact example the sql would be:

```
 $bHasAdminAccess = db::getValue("SELECT count(*) FROM _USER_TABLE_ WHERE userid = ".$userIdLoggedIn." AND userid IN (SELECT userid FROM _USER_TABLE_ LIMIT 2)");
```

well the question should be, why the first two? Can't you simply say lower than two?

```
$bHasAdminAccess = db::getValue("SELECT count(*) FROM _USER_TABLE_ WHERE userid = ".$userIdLoggedIn." AND userid <= 2");
```

In case the id's could change, i would simply add another column "is_admin", so the table would look like:

```
  1    |  Mike   |  1
  2    |  Peter  |  1
  3    |  Drake  |  0
  4    |  Oliver |  0
  5    |  Andrew |  0
```

Than the code would be:

```
$bHasAdminAccess = db::getValue("SELECT count(*) FROM _USER_TABLE_ WHERE userid = ".$userIdLoggedIn." AND is_admin = 1");
```

Comment: No, I can't say it lower than two because employee ID can be 4 digit also or 5 digit etc. The table I demonstrated was just an example.

Comment: Hey I just fixed it for your example, now i get the first two ids and than check it.

Comment: @Arpit_K `$bHasAdminAccess = db::getValue("SELECT count(*) FROM _USER_TABLE_ WHERE userid = ".$userIdLoggedIn." AND userid IN (SELECT userid FROM _USER_TABLE_ LIMIT 2)")`

Answer (score 0):

Well to get first two employee you can use `ORDER BY` clause in query as:

`SELECT * FROM employee_table ORDER BY EMP_ID ASC LIMIT 2`

Now you can match the `session user` with the `EMP_ID` which you will get as a part of result after this query.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I am not getting how to compare it with session user. Because query results two rows so how to take both employee id's and compare it with session user.

Comment: You can have a loop of result you  get from query. If any id is going to match you can redirect to admin page else you can restrict it.